# Repeat headers when using xtable with longtable option

Tags: r, latex, xtable, longtable

Is there a way to repeat the top row / set headers when generating an xtable with a longtable option ?

For eg., if I have

```
tableSb <- xtable(df, caption="A Very Long Table", label="ALongTable")
print(tableSb, include.rownames=TRUE, tabular.environment="longtable", floating=FALSE)
```

This works fine, but when the tables roll over into a new page the headers are not repeated. Any suggestions ?

Comment: This has already been answered (twice):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279956/header-on-each-page-of-big-table-of-xtable

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423423/split-xtable-ouput-into-sub-tables

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be getting any more answers, has any one of those below solved your issue? If so, you can select it as accepted, which will improve your reputation on SO.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, you'll need to use the `add.to.row` option of the `print` function (run `?print.xtable` for more information).

Try this (adapted from [a post on R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=4864&aid=1627&group_id=1228))

```
addtorow          <- list()
addtorow$pos      <- list()
addtorow$pos[[1]] <- c(0)
addtorow$command  <- c(paste(
  "\\hline \n",
  "\\endhead \n",
  "\\hline \n",
  "{\\footnotesize Continued on next page} \n",
  "\\endfoot \n",
  "\\endlastfoot \n",
  sep=""))
x.big <- xtable(
  x,
  label = "tabbig",
  caption = "Example of longtable spanning several pages")
print(
  x.big,
  tabular.environment = "longtable",
  floating = FALSE,
  include.rownames = FALSE,  # because addtorow will substitute the default row names 
  add.to.row = addtorow,     # this is where you actually make the substitution
  hline.after=c(-1))         # because addtorow will substitute the default hline for the first row
```

It's a bit clumsy of a solution, but at least it'll provide you with plenty of customization.

Comment: Is the floating=FALSE statement in print.xtable absolutely essential? I'd like to have an xtable capable of rolling over into a new page AND being in a sidewaystable environment so it is in landscape orientation?

Comment: @gvrocha: If I recall correctly, you're right. `floating` can be set to `TRUE` without a problem.

Comment: At least with xtable 1.7-4, `floating` is set to `FALSE` with a warning automatically. Therefore, there seems to be no way of encapsulating `longtable` in another environment (see also [this feature request](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2249&group_id=1228&atid=4864)).

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code for print.xtable, the only considerations it makes when `tabular.environment="longtable"` are

- Emitting a warning if you also set `floating=TRUE`
- Putting the caption in the right place for a longtable (top or bottom)

It does not emit the code specific for repeating the headers on subsequent pages.  Check out `latex` in the `Hmisc` package.  I know it has support for longtables as well, but I don't recall if it repeats headers correctly.

Comment: Specifically, you'd be looking for a way to replace the line break (\\) following the column headers with \endhead. I don't see that option, so one might have to do it manually.