# Xtable two columns using longtable customizations

Tags: r, knitr, xtable, longtable

This is a continuation of a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253171/two-tables-not-hard-coded-side-by-side-in-latex-that-will-page-break) I posted earlier. I have a `code.Rnw` file in RStudio which I knit into a `code.tex` file using `knit("code.Rnw")` command.

I have a data frame that I am printing using the xtable command. In the example below, it is 20 rows. However, to save space, I am printing it out as two columns, each with 10 rows.

Below is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE,results='asis'>>=
library(xtable)
set.seed(1)

spaceCol =  rep("     ",10)
df1 = data.frame(student = letters[1:10], vals=runif(10, 1, 10))
df2 = data.frame(student = letters[11:20], vals=runif(10, 1, 10))
dfFull = data.frame(df1,spaceCol,df2)
names(dfFull) = c(" ","% Correct","     "," ", "% Correct")
row.names(dfFull) = NULL

x.big <- xtable(dfFull, label ='tabtwo',caption ='Caption for table with student scores')
print(x.big, tabular.environment ='longtable', floating = FALSE, include.rownames=FALSE)
@

\end{document}
```

This is what the output looks like:

[image: Current output]

I like the aesthetics of this output, especially because in the longtable format, this output will automatically page-break if need be. However, what I am trying to improve, is to make it more easy to visualize that this output is really two distinct columns.

To do that, I would like to add a space between the two columns, so the output looks more as follows:

[image: Desired output]

However, if that proves impossible, then I could consider something like adding a vertical line to distinguish the two columns, as shown below:

[image: Alternative desired output]

How might this be possible given my limitation in using xtable?

Comment: One easy thing you could do is adding `align = c("rrrr|lr")` to your `xtable` call. I think the only way to achieve your original goal is to manually use a subfigure. This should not be too difficult, but inolves some manual writing of LaTeX instead of just letting knitr and xtable do the work for you. However, I don't think that there is an alternative as knitr is able to create subfigures, but as to my knowledge only with graphs.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

<<echo = FALSE>>=
library(xtable)

opts_chunk$set(
  echo = FALSE,
  results = 'asis'
)

set.seed(1)

mynames <- c("", "% Correct")

df1 = data.frame(letters[1:10], runif(10, 1, 10))
df2 = data.frame(student = letters[11:20], vals=runif(10, 1, 10))

colnames(df1) <- mynames
colnames(df2) <- mynames
@

\begin{table}\centering
\subfloat{
<<>>=
print(xtable(df1), floating = FALSE, include.rownames = FALSE)
@
} \hspace{2cm}
\subfloat{
<<>>=
print(xtable(df2), floating = FALSE, include.rownames = FALSE)
@
}
\caption{Caption for table with student scores} \label{tabtwo}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

The only drawback is, that you cannot use `longtable` with this approach.

**UPDATE**: Here is an alternative that makes use of `longtable`. The trick is to use `xtable` for the `contents` of the table only and build the headline by hand, so you have full control over all lines etc. I decided to use an empty column for the space because making column 2 wider would make the horizontal lines look ugly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

<<echo = FALSE>>=
library(xtable)

opts_chunk$set(
  echo = FALSE,
  results = 'asis'
)

set.seed(1)

df1 = data.frame(letters[1:10], runif(10, 1, 10))
df2 = data.frame(student = letters[11:20], vals=runif(10, 1, 10))

dfFull <- cbind(df1, NA, df2)
@

\begin{longtable}{lrl@{\hskip 2cm}lr} \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5}
 & \% Correct & & & \% Correct \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5}
<<>>=
print(xtable(dfFull), only.contents = TRUE, include.rownames = FALSE, include.colnames = FALSE, hline.after = NULL)
@
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-5}
\caption{Caption for table with studen scores} \label{tabtwo}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

**UPDATE2**: Finally, a solution that uses `longtable` and doesn't involve creating half of the table "by hand". The trick is to remove all horizontal lines (`hline.after = NULL`) and than add `\clines` where required using `add.to.row` (inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450141/repeat-headers-when-using-xtable-with-longtable-option?rq=1)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

<<echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'>>=
library(xtable)

set.seed(1)


df1 = data.frame(letters[1:10], runif(10, 1, 10))
df2 = data.frame(letters[11:20], runif(10, 1, 10))

dfFull <- cbind(df1, NA, df2)

# To test "longtable", rbind data several times:
multiply <- 5
dfFull <- do.call("rbind", replicate(multiply, dfFull, simplify = FALSE))

colnames(dfFull) <- c("", "% Correct", "", "", "% Correct")

print(xtable(dfFull,
             caption = "Caption for table with student scores",
             label = "tabtwo",
             align = c("l",  # ignored (would apply to colnames)
                       "l", "r",
                       "l@{\\hskip 2cm}", # space between blocks
                       "l", "r")),
      include.rownames = FALSE,
      include.colnames = TRUE,
      hline.after = NULL, # Remove all default lines. A line after the very last row remains, which is automatically added when using "longtable".
      tabular.environment = "longtable",
      floating = FALSE,
      add.to.row = list(
        pos = list(-1, 0),
        command = rep("\\cline{1-2} \\cline{4-5}", 2))
      )
@
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @user2706569, but this solution does not take into account the page break! If I increase the number of rows, it will just run off the page.

Comment: Yes. I see two possible solutions. A: Find a solution that does not use subfigures, then you can easily use `longtable` (my comment on your question may help). B: Find a way to include a `longtable` into subfigures. This is a pure LaTeX problem. (C: Split the table manually)

Comment: Also thank you for your suggestion regarding using the align call in xtable. Yes, that does add the vertical line I desired. I would rather have a vertical space than the vertical line, so I will see if anyone has ideas for that for a little bit. Otherwise, I will keep the line!

Comment: Thanks again. Can you explain a bit more what you mean by the third option... splitting the table manually? I just want to make sure I understand what that means so I can research it!

Comment: What I mean is something like `print(xtable(df1[1:10,])); print(xtable(df1[11:20,]))` if you know that you will need a page break after the first 10 rows. But be careful - your document may change and so will the available space. Therefore, I do not consider this a good solution. Alternatively: Use one table with `only.contents = TRUE, include.colnames = FALSE, hline.after = NULL` and build the "header" on your own.

Comment: I included the idea from the last comment into my answer.