# Column names on each page with xtable in Sweave

Tags: r, latex, sweave, xtable

I want to have column names on each page of the xtable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

<<>>=
x <- matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 10)
x.big <- xtable(x,label='tabbig',caption='Example of longtable spanning several pages')
@

<<label = tabSEM.S, echo = FALSE, results = tex >>=
print(x.big,tabular.environment='longtable',floating=FALSE)
@

\end{document}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/ exists.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this is really a LaTeX question, which I simply Googled and ended up with a simple answer from tex.stackexchange.com [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11380/how-to-repeat-top-rows-column-headings-on-every-page).

Try this (untested in LaTeX; will be curious if this compiles the way you want):

```
print(x.big,tabular.environment='longtable',
        floating=FALSE,
        hline.after = c(-1,nrow(x.big)),
        add.to.row = list(pos = list(0),command = "\\hline \\endhead "))
```

Comment: Thanks @joran for your help and time. Appreciated.